# Trouble printing a Selenium Element list (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not FirefoxWebElement)

Tags: python, list, selenium

I know that selenium stores multiple elements as a list, but I can't iterate over this list to print text?
If so why can I print `print(catagoryInfo[0].text)` without throwing any errors?
Here's my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

import webbrowser
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'http://twitch.tv/directory'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(4)

catagoryInfo = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='tw-card-body tw-relative']")
print(catagoryInfo[0].text)

for i in catagoryInfo:
    print(catagoryInfo[i].text)

browser.close()
```

And the output:

Among Us
70.3K viewers
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\thebr\OneDrive\code\python\TwitchScrape\twitchScrape.py", line 17, in 
print(catagoryInfo[i].text)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not FirefoxWebElement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not iterating trough indexes you should do:

```
for i in catagoryInfo:
    print(i.text)
```

or you could do

```
for i in range(len(catagoryInfo)):
    print(catagoryInfo[i].text)
```

Comment: I can't believe I actually made this error. Thanks so much! Completely forget that i is representing the list itself and not just an integer for positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know '`for`' with iterate the '`catagoryInfo`'.

I think '`catagoryInfo`' isn't an `iteratable` list or others.

So if you used '`for`', '`i`' will be an object in the object '`catagoryInfo`',not an **index** like 1,2,3...